# How to add ID when button is clicked?

Tags: asp.net

I want to add the value of TID when `viewdatesbutton.jpg` is clicked so I can pass it to another web page.

How can I do this?

code:

```
<asp:repeater id="Repeater1" datasourceid="SqlDataSource1" runat="server">

<itemtemplate>

<div class="content-1g">
    <div class="content-1-1g">
        </div>
    <div class="content-1-2g"><p class="none"><%# Eval("TName")%></p><p><span style="color:#FFFFFF"><%# Eval("TDetails")%></span></p>
        <div class="content-1-2ag">
            <div class="content-1-3g">Duration: <%# Eval("TDuration")%> </div>
            <div class="content-1-3g">Adult: £<%# Eval("TPriceadult")%> </div>
            <div class="content-1-3g">Senior/Student: £<%# Eval("TPricesenior")%> </div>
            <div class="content-1-3g">Child: £<%# Eval("TPricechild")%> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-1-2bg"><img alt="" src="/images/viewdatesbutton.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="line"><hr class="top" /></div>

</itemtemplate>

</asp:repeater>

    <asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1"  runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ChinatowndbConnString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT TID, TName, TDetails, TDuration, TPriceadult, TPricesenior, TPricechild FROM [Tour] WHERE TEventCategory=2">
 </asp:sqldatasource>
```

I assume I can have a function on a onclick to the button?  How do I pass the value of TID on it?

Regards,
Tea

EDIT:

```
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbYear" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnCommand="redirectnewpage" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("TourId")%>'>
            <asp:Image ID="imgFolder" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/viewdatesbutton.jpg" />
        </asp:LinkButton>


protected void redirectnewpage(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("book.aspx?tourid="+ e.CommandArgument.ToString());
}
```

Comment: you can add an <input type="hidden"/> or if you need the value on server side, use asp:HiddenField. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`<asp:ImageButton>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx) server side control and use of `CommandArgument` property of it:

```
<div class="content-1-2bg">
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" 
         ImageUrl="/images/viewdatesbutton.jpg" 
         CommandArgument='<%# Eval("TID") %>' 
         OnCommand="ImgButton_OnCommand" />

</div>
```

and then get the `TID` value in the `OnCommand` event handler:

```
private void ImgButton_OnCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var tid = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
}
```

Comment: @TeaDrinkingGeek: yeah, but one `ImageButton` is easier than two server side `Linkbutton` + `Image`, as for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ImageButton to your Template, and use the `CommandArgument` to insert the TID.
For instance:

```
<asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/icon.png" ID="TIDButton" runat="server"  
                 CommandArgument=<%# Eval("TID") %> OnClick="TIDButton_Click" />
```

Then, to get it in your code behind:

```
    protected void TIDButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ImageButton b = sender as ImageButton;
        if (b == null)
          return; 

        string TID = b.CommandArgument;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbYear" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnCommand="redirectnewpage" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("TourId")%>'>
            <asp:Image ID="imgFolder" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/viewdatesbutton.jpg" />
        </asp:LinkButton>


protected void redirectnewpage(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("book.aspx?tourid="+ e.CommandArgument.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbYear" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnCommand="redirectnewpage" CommandArgument='<%#"tourId="+Eval("TourId").ToString()+"&TID="+Eval("TID").ToString()%>'>
        <asp:Image ID="imgFolder" runat="server" ImageUrl="/images/viewdatesbutton.jpg" />
    </asp:LinkButton>


protected void redirectnewpage(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("book?"+ e.CommandArgument.ToString());
}
```